# Hibernate generate m + 1 queries in Many-to-one

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

My problem is very simple but I don't know how to make Hibernate does the way I want:
- table MainTable have Many-2-One with ParentTable (with 100 rows). MainTable point to m=26 rows out of 100 rows in ParentTable

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

When I simply query "from MainTable"

it will generate 26 + 1 queries

When I trace the queries, the 1st query only load PARENT_ID used by 26 later queries. I guess it should have the way to load the whole PARENT_TABLE in the 1st query..

Please help by assuming that:

- FetchType.EAGER is a MUST
- Using **from MainTable mt left join fetch mt.parent parent** is ok but we have many association

Comment: Avoiding N+1 selects problem: http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/hib-tip-pitfall.php?name=n1selects         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem

Comment: @Pangea : Thanks but here some comments: 1) Using fetch join is good, but we have about ten Parent table. That will be the last solution 2) We want something similar to Subselect fetch in One-2-Many, so that 1 query for MainTable, 1 more for related table

Comment: @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) and @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) give no diff at all !!! o_0

Comment: I have never got eager fetch working in my previous projects :P it works in some case but causing more problem in other, especial for XxxToMany relationship.  I remember in Hibernate's document, it has talked about in which situation eager fetch will/will not work.  I would recommend making all of them lazy, and do eager fetch explicitly using join fetch .

Answer (score 4):

```
 // Annotate ParentTable Persistance class file with a batch Size 
 @BatchSize(size=100)
 class ParentTable{
     ..
 }
```

---

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
```

This will reduce the number of queries by n/100+1.

The reason for this issue is that, the hibernate will fetch the data in lazy mode internally, (*I am not  talking about the `FetchMode.Lazy`*). The Lazy mode can be excluded by using `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`, which is applicable only for collections. When it comes to `@ManyToOne`, you can select a `batch` of data, by specifying the `batchSize`.

**A short Description about Fetch Startegies**

`FetchMode.SUBSELECT`

> One Query for parent, One Query for the Related table. Applicable only
>   for Collections framework. Only 2 queries fired.

`FetchMode.SELECT`

> One Query For Parent, N Queries for the Child.

`FetchMode.JOIN`

> One Query for Parent, N Queries for Child, but the database retrieval
>   take place upfront in JOIN.

`FetchType.Batch`

> One Query for parent and n/batchSize + 1 number of queries fired.

---

**There are two type of fetching, based on when the queries should be executed.**

`FetchType.EAGER` :

> The queries are fired instantly.

`FetchType.LAZY` :

> The queries are fired when the child object is accessed. So number of
>   of queries executed will depent on the number of child objects
>   accessed.

[**How the Fetch Strategies work is better explained here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18605401/1844148).