# Model Class running Multiple Queries in Hibernate..!

Tags: java, hibernate

When I use hibernate relations mapping using

```
@OneToOne 
@oneToMany
@ManyToOne
```

relations its making multiple Queries, for every fetch.

Can anyone help me understanding how the  relations work..??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Hibernate Relations Works with different Fetch Strategies..!!

**Hibernate provides 4 strategies for retrieving data:**

**SELECT**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tableName", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(name="id") 
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
```

> In this Method there are Multiple SQLs fired. This first one is fired
>   for retrieving all the records in the Parent table. The remaining are
>   fired for retrieving records for each Parent Record. This is basically
>   the N+1 problem. The first query retrieves N records from database, in
>   this case N Parent records. For each Parent a new query retrieves
>   Child. Therefore for N Parent, N queries retrieve information from
>   Child table.

**JOIN**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tableName", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(name="id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

> This is similar to the SELECT fetch strategy except that fact that all
>   database retrieval take place upfront in JOIN fetch unlike in SELECT
>   where it happens on a need basis. This can become an important
>   performance consideration.

**SUBSELECT**

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="tableName", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @Column(name="id")
 @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

> Two SQLs are fired. One to retrieve all Parent and the second uses a
>   SUBSELECT query in the WHERE clause to retrieve all child that has
>   matching parent ids.

**BATCH**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tableName", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@Column(name="id")
@@BatchSize(size=2)
```

> The batch size maps to the number of Parent whose child are retrieved.
>   So we can specify the number of records to be fetched at a time.But
>   Multiple queries will be executed.!!
>
> ***one-to-many & many-to-many allows - join, Select and SubSelect***
>
> ***many-to-one & one-to-one allows - Join and Select***

---

**Hibernate also distinguishes between (when is the associations are fetched)**

1.**Immediate fetching** -

> an association, collection or attribute is fetched immediately, when
>   the Parent is loaded. (lazy=“false”)

2.**Lazy collection fetching** -

> a collection is fetched when the application invokes an operation upon
>   that collection. (This is the default for collections.(lazy=“true”)

3."**Extra-lazy**" collection fetching -

> individual elements of the collection are accessed from the database
>   as needed. Hibernate tries not to fetch the whole collection into
>   memory unless absolutely needed (suitable for very large collections)
>   (lazy=“extra”)

4.**Proxy fetching** -

> a single-valued association is fetched when a method other than the
>   identifier getter is invoked upon the associated object.
>   (lazy=“proxy”)

5."**No-proxy**" fetching -

> a single-valued association is fetched when the instance variable is
>   accessed. Compared to proxy fetching, this approach is less lazy.(lazy=“no-proxy”)

6.**Lazy** attribute fetching -

> an attribute or single valued association is fetched when the instance
>   variable is accessed.  (lazy=“true”)
>
> ***one-to-many & many-to-many allows Immediate, Layzy, Extra Lazy***
>
> ***many-to-one & one-to-one allows Immediate Proxy, No Proxy***